# Compare two arrays to find their same values

Tags: php

Here is two numeric array:

```
$a = array(0 => '1,3');

$b = array(
    0 => '1,2,4',
    1 => '1,2',
    2 => '4,3',
    3 => '2,4',
    4 => '1,3'
);
```

I want to compare these two arrays and find their same values. For example, in this case `[0] => 1,3` in the first array is matching with `[4] => 1,3` in the second one.

I tried to achieve this by using `array_diff` but with no success. Can any one help this out?

Comment: What should be as a result?

Comment: result is like if its matching echo "its matching " else not matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_search()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to search within array a given value:

```
$a = array(0 => '1,3');
$b = array(
    0 => '1,2,4',
    1 => '1,2',
    2 => '4,3',
    3 => '2,4',
    4 => '1,3'
);

foreach ($a as $val) {
    if ($key = array_search($val, $b)) {
        echo "'$val' is matched in '$key' index";
        break;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
'1,3' is matched in '4' index
```

You can also do the following:

```
$match = array();
foreach ($a as $val) {
    if (array_search($val, $b)) {
        $match[] = $val;
    }
}

print_r($match);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,3
)
```

**Update:**

As the OP mentioned, for this purpose we use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function as well:

```
$a = array(0 => '1,3');
$b = array(
    0 => '1,2,4',
    1 => '1,2',
    2 => '4,3',
    3 => '2,4',
    4 => '1,3'
);

print_r(array_intersect($a, $b));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,3
)
```